# Протокол imap, почта mail.ru

Tags: python, email, mail.ru

Дорогие форумчане! Недавно начал работать с протоколом imap и столкнулся со следующей проблемой...
Мне нужно авторизоваться в почте mail.ru и прочитать сообщение, но для этого требуется разрешение на работу с imap (подтверждается в настройках аккаунта), и делается такое действие вручную. Возникает вопрос: Как можно реализовать разрешение на работу с imap, не заходя в аккаунт?

Comment: Что значит "не заходя в аккаунт"? А то так можно и на чужом аккаунте включить

Comment: Имеется ввиду не заходя вручную, например через запросы и т.п.

Comment: ну может и можно, но для этого нужно зайти вручную и дать разрешение